# Wolfram Alpha plotting error?

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric, wolfram-alpha

I think many people are familiar with the Folium of Descartes:

$$ x^{3}+y^{3}-3axy=0\,.$$

Choosing $\; p =\frac yx\; $ produces a rational parametric equation:

$$ x = \frac{3at}{1+t^3}; \quad y = \frac{3at^2}{1+t^3}$$

that after plotting results in a continuous curve.

Whereas WA produces this [obviously incorrect plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+3t%2F(1%2Bt%5E3);+y+%3D+3t**2%2F(1%2Bt%5E3)) (here $ a = 1 $, but that doesn't really matter).

The reasoning behind this is beyond my comprehension, but I'm afraid it can be a sign of a more major issue with parametric plots.

There are fewer issues with [the plot of the polar version of the same equation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+polar+r+%3D+(3sint+*+cos+t)%2F(sin**3+t+%2B+cos**3+t)), yet the asymptote $\; y  = -x -a \;$   is still present as a part of the curve for some reason.

What is happening here?

Comment: **Formatting tip:** instead of using repeated "quads" such as `$\quad\quad\quad x^{3}+y^{3}-3axy=0$`  to put equations in "display mode", simply use double $ signs as such: `$$x^{3}+y^{3}-3axy=0$$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because WolframAlpha is plotting for $-5.784 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$. Apparently it deems this to be the most useful plot range, for reasons unknown to me. The asymptote appears as it attempts to plot over any range containing $0$, where it decides it needs to zip over from one side of the graph to the other. I agree this is suboptimal.

I don't know how to get WA to plot from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, I'm afraid, but you can get a better result by telling it to plot between larger values.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds reasonable. I've read several similar questions and reported the bug, thus I declare the thread closed.